# LDAP authentication with VB.NET

Tags: asp.net

Is there any a working example of how to connect to LDAP using VB.net?
What it the corret LDAP:// path?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see many examples (in C#):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#39

For the syntax, here is an example:

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, user, password);